# convert a single firestore firebase field from string to int

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, converters

I've managed to store data inside firebase using cloud firestore

I've created a collection that can stores the users extra details like their age, height, and weight

There's a feature in my app that is able to calculate the user's drinking water rate by day based on their weight, the calculation is user's weight divided by 30

So when the user open the page it will directly calculate it.

However. The type of data that stored in firestore is identified as String, and I've been trying to convert the data field type to Int so the program will execute. But I got errors like

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference@a4443fb"

```
public class drinkingWater extends BaseMainMenu {

    TextView cRslt;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore mStore;
    String userID;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drinking_water);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        cRslt = findViewById(R.id.result);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        DocumentReference docRef = mStore.collection("userDetail").document(userID);
        docRef.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                int n1 = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(mStore.collection("userDetail").document(userID + "Weight")));
                int n2 = 30;
                int sum = n1 / n2;
                cRslt.setText(String.valueOf(sum));



            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: You're effectively calling `toString()` on a `DocumentReference` object, which isn't the same as getting a field value at all. I suspect you actually want to be using `documentSnapshot` in the code... you're not using it anywhere at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet what can I do to fix this ? Can you write for me the right way ?

Comment: I haven't used the Java Firestore API, but I suggest you read some tutorials on it - the problem isn't "converting an integer into a string" - it's "accessing a field value". I strongly suspect you want to call `docRef.get()` in order to asynchronously fetch a document snapshot, then get the values from that snapshot.

Comment: @JonSkeet it's converting a string into an integer

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @KilleingMaChin: It's converting the string representation of a DocumentReference object. *That's not what you want.* First focus on getting the data from the document, and log the value you receive. Until you get the field value as a string correctly, nothing else matters.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code correctly you have a `Weight` field in the document, and you want to get the value of that field. You can get the data from the [`DocumentSnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) with:

```
documentSnapshot.get("Weight)
```

So if `Weight` is stored as an integer value, that'd be:

```
int n1 = documentSnapshot.get("Weight)
```

And if `Weight` is stored as a string representation of an int value, it'd be:

```
int n1 = Integer.valueOf(documentSnapshot.get("Weight));
```

Comment: I've added the last code since it's the correct one, it gives me this error : Cannot resolve method 'valueOf(java.lang.Object)' @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Thank you it worked, I've just added : int n1 = Integer.valueOf((String)documentSnapshot.get("Weight));

Answer (score -1):

The error is saying that you cannot convert a string of type `text` to a direct integer. If your string contains any text, it cannot be converted to a number. And I see that you are also `parsing UserId`,`"userDetail` into `Integer` which is impossible. First, you take all the text out of your string in another variable and after then you can easily convert the variable containing `weight` from string to integer. make sure that your `weight` variable is only in number format.

Comment: That wouldn't even compile as you're trying to assign an `Integer` to a `String` variable - and it doesn't address the main actual problem that `String.valueOf(mStore.collection("userDetail").document(userID + "Weight"))` won't return the string representation of an integer.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for this, I haven't seen that he also added `String.valueOf` inside `Integer.valueOf`.

Comment: @MDev I put it before int n1 and it give me this error:  change variable userweight type to Integer

Comment: @KilleingMaChin now, use Integer.parseInt(yourWeight);

Comment: how to apply it and link it to the collcetion and the calculation

Comment: @KilleingMaChin first, get `userUid` and collection in a different variable, then get `Weight` of your particular user and calculate it by `Parsing it into Integer`. I can suggest you if I get an example of your `userId`, `Collection`, and weight.

Comment: @MDev tbh I don't fully understand your idea

Comment: @KilleingMaChin add some more code to your question.